# Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Cannot find record to change state

Tags: dynamics-crm

Has anyone resolved this error before **Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Cannot find record to change state**

The error occurs in the below code.
The error also occurs on a set state workflow actions.

```
 Guid jobCode = _generalLedger.FindJobCode(importRecord.sms_jobcode); 
 Guid chartOfAccounts = _generalLedger.FindChartOfAccountName(importRecord.sms_chartofaccountcode); 

 var ft = sms_financialtransaction()
 {
            sms_date = DateTime.ParseExact(importRecord.sms_datepaid, _dateFormats, null, DateTimeStyles.None),
            sms_EventId = new EntityReference(sms_event.EntityLogicalName, eventId),
            sms_totalamount = new Money(decimal.Parse(importRecord.sms_amountdonated)),
            sms_fullnameid = new EntityReference(Contact.EntityLogicalName, contactId),
            sms_jobnumberid = new EntityReference(sms_job.EntityLogicalName, jobCode),
            sms_chartofaccountid = new EntityReference(sms_chartofaccount.EntityLogicalName, chartOfAccounts),
            sms_source = new OptionSetValue((int)sms_financialtransactionsms_source.RoyalLifeSaving),
            statuscode = new OptionSetValue((int)sms_financialtransaction_statuscode.Completed)
 };

_serviceContext.AddObject(ft);
_serviceContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: What is the value of "(int)sms_financialtransaction_statuscode.Completed" because I think sms_financialtransaction is a custom entity and "(int)sms_financialtransaction_statuscode.Completed" is the deactivated state. You can't create records in the deactivated state. You first need to create it in the active state and then do an update (CRM 2016+) or a SetStateRequest (pre CRM 2016) to deactivate the record.

Comment: Great suggestion, I didn't think to check this, unfortunately,
sms_financialtransaction_statuscode.Completed is a status reason for an Active financial transaction.

Comment: Is there any plugin/real time workflow being trigger when that record is created?

Comment: This is caused by a workflow that is triggered when the recrod is created.